# Eclipse - refreshing workspace when synchronizing with SVN takes forever

Tags: eclipse, subversive

I'm using the [Subversive](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) plugin for Eclipse 4.9.

When I try to synchronize my local workspace with the SVN repository, the loading takes forever, because Eclipse first tries to refresh my local workspace:

[image: screenshot from Eclipse]

I face this problem everyday for the first SVN synchronize operation I do. Then I must kill Eclipse through the task manager (the stop icon does not work) and re-start it. After restarting it, magically SVN synchronization works fine.

I've tried to re-install the SVN plugin, but it didn't fixed the problem.

This is my `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-clean
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.100.v20180827-1352.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.800.v20180827-1352
-vmargs
-server
-Xmn128m
-Xms2048m
-Xmx4096m
-Xss2m
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
-DEDL_XPandBasedSerializer=true
-DTooltipUseBrowserControlGTK=false
-DJGenTemplateDevelopmentMode=true
-DGradleTooling_avoidIntershopGradleProject=false
-DGradleTooling_avoidGradleAutoRefresh=false
-DETest_useClassPathEnvironmentVariable=false
```

I've already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359704/eclipse-refreshing-workspace-takes-forever), but I think that the FileSync plugin is not the correct solution for me, because all the files of the projects I work on are in my local computer and are shared through a remote SVN repository.

I have 19 projects opened in my Eclipse workspace, but I can't close any of them.

Comment: not sure this will work , but try disconnecting svn from eclipse and then reconnect again  - https://www.google.com/search?q=disconnect+svn+in+eclipse&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN832IN832&oq=disconnect+svn&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0l7.7617j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Or try [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x) instead of Subversive.